# Unable to insert mysql database through form data

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a form where I want to insert mysql database when I submit the values but when I click on the submit button the database isnt updated.. dont know where I am going wrong in my code..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Data</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="form.php" method="post">

Server Name: <input type="text" name="server_name"> <br />
IP Address: <input type="text" name="ip_address"> <br />
Server Role: <input type="text" name="server_role"> <br />

<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "abcx";
$dbname = "serverasset_inventory";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);


$sql = "INSERT INTO asset_inventory (server_name,ip_address,server_role)
VALUES ('$_POST[server_name]','$_POST[ip_address]'),'$_POST[server_role]')";
$state = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
mysqli_close($connection);

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

-A

Comment: Because you were not `updating` you were `inserting`

Comment: Sorry for the typo.. I meant insert ..its still very early in the morning and I wanted to fix  this!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to debug your errors..!! Please do some research before posting the question here. The question seems to be an entry level basic syntax error. There is no signs of research effort whatsoever shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using a extra bracket between query and missing quote in variable's use like below

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `asset_inventory` (`server_name`,`ip_address`,`server_role`)
VALUES ('".$_POST['server_name']."','".$_POST['ip_address']."','".$_POST['server_role']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to insert the fields 
for example

your sql will be take in variables then insert it in sql

```
$server_name = $_POST['server_name'];
$ip_address = $_POST['ip_address'];
$server_role = $_POST['server_role'];



 insert into  asset_inventory (server_name,ip_address,server_role) VALUES ('$server_name','$ip_address','$server_role';
```